# Using VBA to run Add-ins with Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have an add-in that uses an highlighted column to search a database to return information I need. This add-in has fields which I can select using a checkbox, is there a way to have a macro check checkboxes with a certain field name?

Comment: Note, I may not have access to what the add-in code itself calls the fields.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, and as asked, the answer is pretty much "yes" or "no". Doesn't seem like a very good fit for SO. You might want to read [ask] in the [help/on-topic].